# Does Google App Engine support incoming streams via sFTP?

Tags: google-app-engine, ftp, sftp, hipaa

Previous answers have eluded to the fact that [Google App Engine now supports FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693412/does-google-app-engine-support-ftp?rq=1) - but does it support sFTP as well for incoming data streams?

We are looking to simulate an sFTP endpoint on GAE to leverage its HIPAA compliance.  If incoming sFTP is not possible on GAE - is there a simple layer of indirection one could create that effectively gives the same level of security yet still looks like an sFTP endpoint to outside systems?

Comment: You cannot listen on a socket on Appengine. You could use GCE or a managed VM, where you have access to sockets, or host a 'proxy' application somewhere (GCE/AWS) that acts as an adapter between sftp and some kind of https endpoint. You can create outbound sockets, so you could in theory connect to an ftp server and pull the data down, but in my experience this is painful and hard. I would look for an alternative to sftp or an alternative to appengine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears according to [Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/) you can only create outbound sockets. "You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets."