# Can Python on Google App Engine act as an FTPs(FTP TLS) or sFTP client?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ftp, sftp

Despite multiple posts on StackOverflow suggesting Google App Engine not supporting FTP using Python, FTP does now work. (We have posted an example of working code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693412/does-google-app-engine-support-ftp/26283142#26283142).)

Given GAE's progress with basic FTP, has anyone found a way for a Google App Engine script to serve as an sFTP or FTPS(FTP TLS) client?

Comment: GAE can not function as a FTP server (since there are no listening sockets), but it can run FTP client if outbound sockets are enabled.

Comment: We are not interested in GAE as an FTP server - rather GAE serving as an FTPS client or sFTP client. Has anyone found that to be possible? (Clarifying edits to question made above.)